# socket design: Handling connection requests TCP/UDP

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

The challenge: We have a number of clients in distributed outposts that I have to manage with a central server. As some clients are located in DMZ or behind proxies, they should be connecting to the server!

As I only have to deal with one client at a time, the server doesn't necessarily have to be able to handle multiple clients simultaniously, however, I would like to see a list of the clients that are trying to connect to the server. Plus, I would like to see more information about the clients than just the IP address, for example the geographic location and some information, if the client has some files in a specific directory that the central server is interested in. My question is, how I best do smth like that.

Sure, I could simply show every client trying to connect in a listbox and accept only the one that I want to connect with, but is that really the way to go? I doubt I can get more information about the client than it's IP address?

I was wondering, if this calls for UDP. The clients send UDP datagrams that just inform the server that they are alive and that they want to connect. On the server, I see all these clients listed with the data they sent. I can then select one client, send an answer/"connection request" with UDP so that this particular client will connect via TCP to the server?

Is that possible?

Comment: If you're interested in avoiding a reinvention of the wheel, I've written a C++ server and library that pretty much handles everything you want to do; you can take a look here:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/  If you're interested in that approach, send me an email or a private message and I'll tell you how to set up a demo of the functionality you want (it would take about 5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like using a hammer to crack a nut. Just have them all connect via TCP. Then you get their presence, their IP address, anything else they care to send you. Deal with them all at once. It's not hard.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, that right now, for every comnected client (as its non blocking), a separate thread is created. So if 100 clients connect, i have 100 threads which is really unfortunate, as i basically only work with one at a time.